How to visualise and know the shape/size of XCOS block? Can we print the output in console
I have one script zcos. There is an issue with the port size and type. How to debug it? Why there is not options to know the or visualize or print in console the output of XCOS block developed?
Resolve and debugging the issue

It's hard to tell based on the info provided, so this might not be what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778249/c-c-code-generation-from-xcos-in-scilab
It's an old answer but seems adjacent to your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have two file which contribute to develop the own toolbox in Scilab/XCOS. And there is issue with " Problem in port size or type".
Its Scicos model , define
